# Analyzer with Code Fix template

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn-code-analysis

I want to create a new project with code analyzer using Roslyn. But I can't find any template for that in my Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

As I know it should be template Analyzer with Code Fix.

I'm a new with the VS, can someone help me, thanks.

Comment: @Sami what do you mean? There is no code, I just want to create project but there isn't template for that kind of project. So, I asked about that. What the information do you need? That's all info that I have. But nevermind, megatron gave the good answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Download and install [.NET Compiller Platform SDK](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.NETCompilerPlatformSDK)

That template is available in the New **Project** dialog box. Expand either the **Visual C#** node, and then choose **Extensibility**.

Another way if there aren't any templates then you need to choose **Install Visual Studio Extensibility Tools**. Download and Install.

After that, choose **Download the .NET Compiller Platform SDK**

And finally you will see the template **Analyzer with Code Fix (NuGet + VSIX)**